# What is the behavior of local_seq under CouchDB 2.x?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

In CouchDB 1.x, documents had a "hidden" `._local_seq` field that tracked the database's [update sequence](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/notifications.html) at the state when the document revision was written. This could be used by views by including the `{local_seq:true}`option in the design document, or fetched by clients using the `?local_seq=true` query option on a document GET request.

This field is still available in CouchDB 2.x, but it is unclear how it behaves. Because of the clustering, the [database update sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446673/update-sequence-changed-semantics-in-cloudant-db) is now "an opaque token" whereas the local_seq is still a plain integer that doesn't seem to always match up in practice.

Is there any relationship, particularly if I limit myself to a single-node cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've figured out so far:

For starters, the purpose of `local_seq` is indeed much less clear under CouchDB 2.x. As already mentioned in the question, at the database/_changes level, the sequence numbers have been replaced by an "opaque token" that officially has no relationship whatsoever to the local_seq.

To make matters worse, it appears that the `local_seq` value stored with [or at least derivable from] each document is not local to the *database* but to the **shard**! (Each database is split into multiple parts internally; you can read more about [Shards and Replicas](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.0/cluster/sharding.html) in the docs for details.)

So whereas in CouchDB 1.x one could, for example, make a custom changes feed by emitting the local_seq as part of a map-reduce index's key — and it would match up with the `?since=N` values of the database's _changes feed — in the cluster-focused CouchDB 2.x such a view would tend to emit multiple documents [up to one from each shard] that have the same `._local_seq` field as each other!

And from the other angle, under CouchDB 2.x, even the `"seq"` associated with a particular document in the database-level _changes feed can change from request to request — both the prefix and/or the big long mess after it. I'm not sure if there's a way, or any useful advantage, that the view engine could provide a "non-local sequence" value to the `map` function like it does with the local sequence.

---

That said, I found a "coincidental" way as of CouchDB 2.3.0 to retain some of the usefulness:

1. By [creating a database](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.0/cluster/databases.html#creating-a-database) with `PUT /newdb?n=1&q=1` — i.e. configuring 1 replica and only 1 shard — the local_seq values end up being unique within a database.
2. In those circumstances, the first part of each `seq` token in database-level _changes feed *also* seems to match up with the local_seq of each changed document. I.e. if you split the string token on `'-'` and convert the first part to a number, you seem to get the local_seq.

I would rely on this with caution, as:

- in the event you *do* need to scale up, and choose to do so by using the multi-node clustering features, any code that relies on the above will break
- it is in no way officially sanctioned, and could theoretically break in so much as a point release. The CouchDB developers have been very clear that the _changes-level tokens are **opaque** and that you should treat them as such.

So *caveat hackor* and all that, the "coincidences" above do match a description of [how these tokens work](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201706.mbox/%3C70C89252-BA26-43F5-BD0B-62A6814EF904%40apache.org%3E) at the moment:

> The number on the front is the sum of the individual update sequences encoded in the second part and exists only to trick older versions of the couchdb replicator into making checkpoints.

✅ If there's only one update sequence, the sum should be the just be the original sequence.

> For a given shard
>   [the _changes feed] *is* totally ordered (a shard being identical to a pre 2.0 database with an integer sequence), couchdb doesn't shuffle that output […]

✅ With only one shard [n.b. *shard*, not simply one *node*/*replica*], you are pretty much left with the pre-2.0 database sort of behavior.